# Java, ResultSet.close(), PreparedStatement.close() -- what for?

Tags: java, database, memory-leaks, connection-leaks

In my web-application, i make extensive use of a database.

I have an abstract servlet, from which all the servlets that need a database connection, inherit. That abstract servlet creates a database connection, calls the abstract method which must be overriden by the inheriting servlets to do their logic, and then closes the connection. I do not use connection pooling, because my application will have a very limited number of users and operations.

My question is, what's the worst that can happen if i don't ever close the `ResultSet`s, `PreparedStatement`s and `Statement`s that my inheriting servlets create, if the `Connection`s that create them are always closed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The javadoc for [Statement#close()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close%28%29) says:

> Note:When a Statement object is closed, its current ResultSet object, if one exists, is also closed.

So you don't need to worry about closing ResultSets, as long as you always close Statements in a timely manner.

The javadoc for [Connection#close()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#close%28%29) does not make a corresponding guarantee, but it does say:

> Releases this Connection object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for them to be automatically released.

Which you might reasonably construe as implying that any statements will be closed. Looking at the open-source jTDS driver, and peeking into the driver for a well-known and expensive commercial database, i can see that they do exactly that.

Comment: Also, in case of connection pooling when you call Connection.close() the connection will be returned to the pool and not actually closed. So one should not rely that Connection.close() will also close statements - it is recommended to always close statements explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

I'm pretty sure closing the connection will close the associated Statements, ResultSets and other associated objects. However all this will consume resources on both the client and may be on the database server until the connection is closed.

If in your case you know that you'll close the connection *really soon* you probably don't risk much although I don't think this should be considered as a best practice.

However this is only valid in your current setting. <strike>If</strike> When your application will change you can face issues because you didn't close your Statements and ResultSets.

Although you don't want to use connection pooling I think it is a bad idea even with few users/operations as opening a database connection is not cheap. So even in your context connection pool may help to get your system more responsive.

Just a note on garbage collection. Before closing the connection, the unused Statements or ResultSets *may* be GCed. **But** when it comes to freeing system resources such as files or more generally non-java resources (such as the cursors on a database server) the JVM GC should not be relied upon. For instance if your client application opens a lot of ResultSets but only use a small fraction of the allocated heap memory, the GC will never kicks in while the database server is *suffocated* by the opened cursors.

Comment: Well, creating pools is also expencive, and when you have only about 5 users (it is a corporate thing), and they make about 1-2 operations an hour, pooling may slow things down, as it will try to look for working connections and then try to create new ones, as the old ones will have "died". And I also try to avoid "premature optimization" :)

Comment: @lbolit - You only create the pool once, at start-up. Otherwise you have to renegotiate a connection on every request. The overhead of a pool lookup is tiny compared to the overhead of creating a request. If you use a pool now, you won't have to fix it when the usage of the app changes.

Comment: @lbolit you're right in your case there is definitely no rush to implement connection pool.

Comment: @OrangeDog - As far as i know, connections in the pool expire after being idle for some period of time, and then they need to be created again, which leads to the same overhead as when creating connections "from scratch". But it's been a while since i last used a connection pool, so i may be wrong.

Comment: @lbolit - Correct, but "some period of time" can usually be whatever you want. If requests are that infrequent then you probably shouldn't care about connection overhead anyway, but pooled connections are easier to manage and will help when the requirements change.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you'll end up exhausting resources on your database server due to tied up file handles, resources needed for holding the result set associated with a given statement etc. There might be smart driver/database implementations out there which make sure that as soon as the connection is closed all the related resources are freed up but that isn't part of the specification so might eventually come and bite you in the long run. Any reason why your overriding classes can't close the result sets and statements they use?

Comment: > Any reason why your overriding classes can't close the result sets and statements they use? -- No particular reason, except that i often forget to write that <code>rs.close()</code> thing, and moreover you have to place them in the <code>finally<code> clause, since DB operations throw SQLExceptions, and that is somewhat cumbersome.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't a strong reason to forgo cleaning up resources. If you are looking for closing your DB resources in a clean way, look into the DBUtils (http://commons.apache.org/dbutils/) project. If you are not comfortable with picking up the entire JAR, you can just snag the source code for the DBUtils class which is responsible for cleaning up of resources and you should be good to go.

Comment: DBUtils provides [closeQuietly](http://xlct.it/fHmaDE) methods which are completely suitable for use in `finally` when you cannot do anything if the call to `close` fails.

Comment: By the way, as far as closing the connections quietly, Java7 is the answer with its new <pre>try</pre> syntax

Comment: I believe Ibolit's comment above meant to say Java's new "try-with-resources" statement. See the Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of crap Api - ends up with you writing a load of boiler plate code.

I reckon the best way to go is wrap the classes and make it so that disposing the connection disposes the other stuff (as you can track what gets made on the way out of the wrapped calls).

As long as you've got an IDE that can generate you delegating methods in a class then it's a trivial job to wrap stuff like this.

I didn't realise all the extra stuff needed disposing but just spotted someone doing it here, however I'm in luck as we are already wrapping the basic classes to turn all the annoying exceptions into RuntimeExceptions and to provide some more high level sql operations.

I made a little class for tracking the different bits of stuff:

```
public class CleanupList
{
    private final ArrayList<AutoCloseable> _disposables;

    public CleanupList()
    {
        _disposables = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void cleanup()
    {
        for(AutoCloseable closeable : _disposables){
            //it sucks that they put an exception on this interface
            //if anyone actually throws an exception in a close method then there's something seriously wrong going on
            //they should have copied the c# more closely imo as it has nicer syntax aswell
            try
            {
                closeable.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        _disposables.clear();
    }

    public <T extends AutoCloseable> T track(T statement)
    {
        _disposables.add(statement);
        return statement;
    }
}
```

And then for example in Wrapped Connection (which is something that wraps a database connection):

```
public class WrappedConnection implements AutoCloseable
{
    private final CleanupList _cleanupList;
    private Connection _connection;

    public WrappedConnection(Connection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
        _cleanupList = new CleanupList();
    }

    public void close()
    {
        try
        {
            _connection.close();
            _cleanupList.cleanup();
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public PreparedStatement prepareStatement(String sql)
    {
        try
        {
            return trackForDisposal(_connection.prepareStatement(sql));
        } 
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private <T extends AutoCloseable> T trackForDisposal(T statement)
    {
        return _cleanupList.track(statement);
    }

.... lots more methods
}
```

You can then also pass the same list into wrapped versions of PreparedStatement/Result sets (which I've not shown here) etc and use it in a similar way.

I don't know what other people are using but in IDEA you can switch on a warning for auto-closable stuff that isn't in a using (or should I say try-with-resources) block:

```
try(SomethingThatNeedsClosing somethingThatNeedsClosing = new SomethingThatNeedsClosing()){
    //do stuff
}
```

These using blocks do you a try finally close automatically and can only be used with things of the AutoClosable interface type

I dont know why this warning isn't switched on by default in IDEA but there you go.

Answer (score 0):

A connection to the database isn't the only thing your application is tying up. There are other resources at stake.

They will get freed up at some point in time if you don't release them yourself, but if can do that, you should.